# google app script のトリガーのオーナーを特定する手段は？

Tags: google-apps-script

google app scriptのトリガーのオーナーを特定する手段があるかどうかの質問となります。

編集者、オーナーを含め複数名で利用、編集しているGASのトリガーですが、所有者不明のトリガーがあります。
トリガーの設定者を特定したいのですが、我々のアカウントからは、オーナーが他のユーザーとしか表示されず困っている状態です。
そのトリガーを設定した方に、トリガーを削除して貰う必要があるのですが、何か、トリガーのオーナーを特定する手段などありますでしょうか?

Comment: 質問からはトリガーの種類やトリガーで動作する具体的なスクリプトを判断することができませんので、この方法が直接の解決策かどうかは不明です。申し訳ありません。例えば、installable OnEdit triggerの場合、トリガー動作時に`Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail()`を実行することでトリガーをインストールしたユーザのメールアドレスを取得することができます。この方法が役に立たない場合は謝罪致します。